# split tags with javascript or other language

Tags: javascript, php

I have a bunch of tags that I need to analyze for my thesis. Because of the amount of work, I am wondering if there is a possibility to automate the process.

I want to break each tag by the number that is shown between the brackets. This number shows the frequency of that tag, but when splitting the tags by hand it is helpful.

Can anyone help me with a JavaScript or PHP script that can split the tags onto a new line?

This is a sample of the tags:

```
1001-import (1) 1001-must-read-2008-edition (1) 1001-must-read-books (2) 1001-must-reads (1) 1001-read (1) 1010 Challenge (1) 10B (1) 10th (1) 11 in 11 (1) 11 in 11 - Read (1) 11 in 11 - Travel (1) 11-22-2011 (1) 11-22-2011take2 (1) 111 Science Fiction (1) 11JAN10 (1) 11th (1) 11th century (1) 12 in 12 (1) 12 år (1) 12/12/13 Tyler Deal - letter sent (1) 12/20/2011 (1) 12th (1) 13 (1) 13 år (1) 131 (1) 14 år (1) 14-15 (1) 15 år (1) 16 år (1) 1659 (1) 168 sidor (1) 17 år (1) 18S (1) 18x11 (1) 1900's (late) (1) 1945-1999 (1) 1950-1999 (1) 1960s-'70s novels (1) 1970 (1) 1970'erne (1) 1970s (36) 1970s authorship (1) 1970s fiction (1) 1979 (27) 1979 pub (1) 1979AD (1) 1980 (2) 1980s (7) 1981 (3) 1981/02 (1) 1982 (3) 1983 (1) 1984 (1) 1986 (1) 1988 (2) 1988-1991 (1) 1989 (1) 1989 reading (1) 1990 (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Can you show exactly your expected output?

Comment: Do you mean `str = str.replace(/\(\d\)/g,"<br/>")` ? or perhaps `var list  = str.split(/\(\d\)/)` ?`

Comment: Hi, thanx for the quick response. I haven't really code something yet, but i was looking for a way to display the enormous mass of data onto single lines. The output  would be something like this:
1001-import (1) <br />
1001-must-read-2008-edition (1) <br />
1001-must-read-books (2) <br />
etc

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting comments

Comment: Like what? **[Edit]** and show it.

Comment: @kjonsson: I downvoted your answer because it doesn't work for the sample data. You didn't revenge-downvote the working answers, did you?

Comment: @kjonsson: I know for a fact you didn't downvote the php one, as the only -1 on there, is mine... Ah well, the working answers are voted above the broken ones. That's what matters.

Answer (score 3):

This JavaScript should do the trick:

```js
var str = "1001-import (1) 1001-must-read-2008-edition (1) 1001-must-read-books (2) 1001-must-reads (1) 1001-read (1) 1010 Challenge (1) 10B (1) 10th (1) 11 in 11 (1) 11 in 11 - Read (1) 11 in 11 - Travel (1) 11-22-2011 (1) 11-22-2011take2 (1) 111 Science Fiction (1) 11JAN10 (1) 11th (1) 11th century (1) 12 in 12 (1) 12 år (1) 12/12/13 Tyler Deal - letter sent (1) 12/20/2011 (1) 12th (1) 13 (1) 13 år (1) 131 (1) 14 år (1) 14-15 (1) 15 år (1) 16 år (1) 1659 (1) 168 sidor (1) 17 år (1) 18S (1) 18x11 (1) 1900's (late) (1) 1945-1999 (1) 1950-1999 (1) 1960s-'70s novels (1) 1970 (1) 1970'erne (1) 1970s (36) 1970s authorship (1) 1970s fiction (1) 1979 (27) 1979 pub (1) 1979AD (1) 1980 (2) 1980s (7) 1981 (3) 1981/02 (1) 1982 (3) 1983 (1) 1984 (1) 1986 (1) 1988 (2) 1988-1991 (1) 1989 (1) 1989 reading (1) 1990 (1)"

var tags = str.split(/\) (?=\w)/g)     // Split that list of tags at every ") " that is followed by a letter.
  .map(function(pair){                 // (So don't split "1900's (late) (1)")
    var values = pair.split(' (');

    var result = {
        amount: parseInt(values.pop()) // The last value in `values` is the count
    }
    result.tag = values.join(' (');    // Restore the remaining string.

    return result;
  });

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace with regex..

update: just added a none capturing group on the regEx to get rid of the white space..  The  `(?:\s)` part does this..  and the `(\d*\)` finds things like `(<number>)`..  Oh, and the `$&` is then used to re-insert the captured `(\d*\)`.  Just in case anyone wondering how it all works.

```js
var input = "1001-import (1) 1001-must-read-2008-edition (1) 1001-must-read-books (2) 1001-must-reads (1) 1001-read (1) 1010 Challenge (1) 10B (1) 10th (1) 11 in 11 (1) 11 in 11 - Read (1) 11 in 11 - Travel (1) 11-22-2011 (1) 11-22-2011take2 (1) 111 Science Fiction (1) 11JAN10 (1) 11th (1) 11th century (1) 12 in 12 (1) 12 år (1) 12/12/13 Tyler Deal - letter sent (1) 12/20/2011 (1) 12th (1) 13 (1) 13 år (1) 131 (1) 14 år (1) 14-15 (1) 15 år (1) 16 år (1) 1659 (1) 168 sidor (1) 17 år (1) 18S (1) 18x11 (1) 1900's (late) (1) 1945-1999 (1) 1950-1999 (1) 1960s-'70s novels (1) 1970 (1) 1970'erne (1) 1970s (36) 1970s authorship (1) 1970s fiction (1) 1979 (27) 1979 pub (1) 1979AD (1) 1980 (2) 1980s (7) 1981 (3) 1981/02 (1) 1982 (3) 1983 (1) 1984 (1) 1986 (1) 1988 (2) 1988-1991 (1) 1989 (1) 1989 reading (1) 1990 (1)";

console.log(input.replace(/\(\d*\)(?:\s)/g,'$&\r\n'));
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why yours or mine got down voted.. Look's like Mr Downvoter is out today.. I'll up-vote yours to balance things.

Comment: Indeed, Balance +1. Check the comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP solution:

```
$t = array();
$tags = "your tags here...";
$tags = explode(")",$tags);
foreach($tags as $tagJunk){
    $tagJunk = explode("(", $tagJunk);
    $t[] = array("tag"=>trim($tagJunk[0]), "count"=>trim($tagJunk[1]));
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://3v4l.org/U2j0k